# AngularJS: Setting up a default value for Select (using string's list)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array with the strings (not objects)
And I binded them to a Select control using AngularJS
But I faced with a problem to set up a default setting because my array contains the strings, not the objects. How can I do it in the most correct way?

This is what I got:

```
 var genders =["Male", "Female"];

<select data-ng-options="o.Name for o in genders track by o.Id"
 data-ng-model="selectedCustomer.Gender"
</select>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if understood correctly. Maybe you set default to the first item in the array. For example: var default = genders[0]. In your case default variable would became "Male"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [DOCs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), You can simply use the expression `label for value in array` for arrays as data-source.

```
<select data-ng-options="o for o in genders" 
        data-ng-model="selectedCustomer.Gender">
</select>
```

You don't need `trackexpr`

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/vn9x52yc/)

Comment: @J.Doe, See https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/vn9x52yc/ Try to avoid using strong words when asking for help